# Why doesn't clicking my button do anything?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to get data from db when user has done 2 inputs, these would be two dates, 1 is the start date and the other one is the end date. When the user clicks on the button, it should retrieve the data from the db as the inputs are given. but when i click on my button, it happens nothing. Does anybody know where my mistake is? These are my two files.

neutest.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Trapeze Stop Point Protocol</title>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- fontawesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- datatables -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <!-- style sheet -->
      <style>
         body
         {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         background-color:#f1f1f1;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container box">
         <h1 align="center">Trapeze Stop Point Protocol</h1>
         <br />
         <?php
            //require('search.php');    
            $conn = oci_connect('IPA_admin','P0o9i8u7','localhost/IPADB');
            If (!$conn)
                echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
            else
                echo 'Connected to Database (Dropdown)';
            $stid = oci_parse($conn,'SELECT DISTINCT STOPPOINT_NAME FROM STOPPOINT_NAMES');
            oci_execute($stid);
            ?>
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <br />
            <div class="row">
               <div align="center" class="col-md-3">
                  <p>PLEASE SELECT BUSSTATION</p>
                  <select name="station" id="station"</select>>
                  <option value="">---Station Wählen---</option>
                  <?php
                     while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) !=false) {
                     ?>             
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['STOPPOINT_NAME']; ?>"
                     <?php
                        if($row['STOPPOINT_NAME']){
                        }
                        ?> >
                     <?php 
                        echo $row['STOPPOINT_NAME'];
                        ?> 
                  </option>
                  <?php
                     }

                     ?>

                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="input-daterange">
                  <div align="col-md-6">
                     <p>VON</p>
                     <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div align="col-md-6">
                     <p>BIS</p>
                     <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" min="1000-01-01" max="3000-12-31" class="form-control">
                  </div>
               </div>
               </br>
               <div align="center" class="col-md-3">
                  <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
               </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <table id="order_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>STOPPOINT ID</th>
                     <th>STOPPOINT NAME</th>
                     <th>DATUM</th>
                     <th>DISTANCE</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                  <?php
                    $conn = oci_connect('IPA_admin','*******','localhost/IPADB');
                    If (!$conn)
                         echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
                    else
                         echo 'Connected to Database (SHOW)';
                    $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM STOPPOINT_NAMES ORDER BY DATUM');
                    oci_execute($stid2);
                    while(($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
                       {
                    ?>  


                  <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row["STOPPOINTID"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["STOPPOINT_NAME"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["DATUM"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["DISTANCE"]; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php  
                     }  
                     ?>
                     </tbody>     
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"search.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                            $('#order_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and this is the code for the button click:

```
<?php  
 //search.php
 //require('neutest.php');  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
    $conn = oci_connect('IPA_admin','*******','localhost/IPADB');    
    $query = oci_parse($conn,'SELECT * FROM STOPPOINT_NAMES WHERE DATUM BETWEEN '.$_POST["from_date"].' AND '.$_POST["to_date"].'');  
    oci_execute($query);
    $output .='
        <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
            <th>STOPPOINT ID</th>  
            <th>STOPPOINT NAME</th>  
            <th>DATUM</th>  
            <th>DISTANCE</th>    
            </tr>  
        ';
      if(oci_num_rows ($query) > 0)  
      {  
        while(($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_BOTH)) != false)  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'. $row["STOPPOINTID"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["STOPPOINT_NAME"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["DATUM"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["DISTANCE"] .'</td> 
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Stops Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: In the future, don't include your db password in your code when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Add form to the html, and change the btn to submit to same page (if the php code of the search is in the same page).

HTML:

```
    <from method="post" id="myForm">
        <div class="input-daterange">
                      <div align="col-md-6">
                         <p>VON</p>
                         <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div align="col-md-6">
                         <p>BIS</p>
                         <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" min="1000-01-01" max="3000-12-31" class="form-control">
                      </div>
        </div>
        </br>
               <div align="center" class="col-md-3">
                  <input type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
               </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "urlToPhpFile",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(result){

        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I think the point is to do it with AJAX as it is a search feature.

Comment: You have smart quotes in your `url` property value which may cause issues.